General solution of $P(s) T = 1$
Suppose that we are given the distribution equation $$P(s) T = 1, \tag{1}$$ where $P(s)$ is a polynomial in $s$ and $T$ is a distribution. What's the solution for $T$ in this equation? I want to find a rigorous answer, rather than a heuristic or intuitive answer. Actually this equation comes up when we try to solve the differential equation$$a_n\frac{d^nT(t)}{dt^n} + a_{n-1}\frac{d^{n-1}T(t)}{dt^{n-1}} + \dots +a_0T(t) = \delta(t), \tag{2}$$ using Fourier transform. In many lecture notes that I've found, like this, both sides of the equation are simply divided by $P(s)$ and then partial fraction decomposition is done but I think this approach is problematic because it ignores homogenous part of the solution. For example in this post, md2perpe's answer shows that the solution to the equation $(1-k^2)Y=0$ is $Y(k)=A\delta(k+1)+B\delta(k-1)$. So it seems that the general solution for the equation $(1)$ is $$T = \frac{1}{P(s)} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i \delta(s-s_i),$$ but I'm not sure whether it's correct in all cases. For instance, I have doubts about the case some of the roots are repeated or polynomial has complex roots.

Relevant: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malgrange%E2%80%93Ehrenpreis_theorem

@cmk Thanks. So Malgrange–Ehrenpreis theorem shows that the equation always have a solution. I'm looking for finding the solution(s) in the general case. Do you know any result which talks about that?

Over $\mathbb R$ a polynomial $P(s)$ can be factored as
$$
P(s) = (s-s_1)^{p_1}\cdots(s-s_k)^{p_k}(s^2+c_1)^{r_1}\cdots(s^2+c_m)^{r_m},
$$
where $s_j\in\mathbb R,$ $c_j>0,$ and $p_j,r_j\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}.$
Each factor $(s-s_j)^{p_j}$ contributes to the homogeneous solution with terms $\sum_{i=0}^{p_j-1} A_i\delta^{(i)}(s-s_j).$ The factors $(s^2+c_j)^{r_j}$ do not contribute with anything.
As a distribution, the expression $\frac{1}{P(s)}$ shall be interpreted as principal value or finite part at $s_j$ depending on whether $p_j$ is odd or even. Those are closely related:
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{fp}\frac{1}{s^{2k+2}} &= -\frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{s^{2k+1}} & (k=0,1,2,\ldots)\\
\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{s^{2k+1}} &= -\frac{1}{2k}\frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{s^{2k}} & (k=1,2,3,\ldots)
\end{align}$$
EDIT:
I realized that the polynomial might have complex (usually either pure real or pure imaginary) coefficients. Then only the real roots contribute with $\delta$ terms in the homogeneous solution.
EXAMPLE:
Consider $P(s)=(s^2+1)(s-1)(s-3)^2.$ Let us look for a homogeneous solution, i.e. solve $P(s)T(s)=0.$
We can start with dividing by $s^2+1.$ There are no problems here since $1/(s^2+1)$ is in $C^\infty(\mathbb R).$ Our problem then simplifies to
$(s-1)(s-3)^2T(s)=0.$
Then we use that $(s-s_0)T(s)=0$ is solved by $T(s)=A\delta(s-s_0)$ for any constant $A.$ Thus,
$(s-3)^2T(s)=A\delta(s-1).$
Next we can take one of the $(s-3)$ factors. Now we have a inhomogeneous equation since the right hand side does not vanish. We want to just multiply by $1/(s-3),$ but realize that this is problematic since $1/(s-3)$ is not smooth. However, if two distributions have disjoint singular support, i.e. if the sets where the two distributions are not smooth are disjoint, then we can actually multiply them. Now, $1/(s-3)$ has singular support $\{3\}$ while $A\delta(s-1)$ has singular support $\{1\}.$ These are disjoint so we can perform the multiplication. We can also simplify the result by $f(s)\delta(s-s_0)=f(s_0)\delta(s-s_0)$:
$$
\frac{1}{s-3}A\delta(s-1) = \frac{1}{1-3}A\delta(s-1) = -\frac12 A\delta(s-1).
$$
We also need to add the solution to the homogeneous equation. This gives a term $B\delta(s-3).$ Thus we have
$$
(s-3)T(s) = -\frac12 A\delta(s-1) + B\delta(s-3).
$$
Finally we take care of the second factor $(s-3).$ For the first term in the right hand side we do as before and get another factor $-\frac12.$ For the $B\delta(s-3)$ term we use that $(s-s_0)\delta'(s-s_0)=-\delta(s-s_0)$ to get $-B\delta'(s-3).$ Then we must add a term for the homogeneous case: $C\delta(s-3).$
Our final solution therefore is
$$
T(s)=\frac14 A\delta(s-1) - B\delta'(s-3) + C\delta(s-3).
$$

Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to understand your answer better by solving a simple example step by step. Suppose that we are given the equation $<(s^2+1)(s-2)(s-3)^2T , \phi> = 1$ which is defined to be $<T , (s^2+1)(s-2)(s-3)^2\phi> = 1$ and $\phi$ is a test function. Now what's the next step? Certainly your answer is correct but I want to find the answer from first principles.

@S.H.W. That's not the correct equation for $(s^2+1)(s-1)(s-3)^2T=1.$ It should be $$\langle (s^2+1)(s-1)(s-3)^2T,\phi \rangle = \langle 1, \phi \rangle.$$

@S.H.W. I suggest that you instead look at solutions to $(s-s_0)T=U,$ where $U$ is a distribution and $s_0$ is a real number. Then build up a solution one factor at a time:
$$(s^2+1)(s-1)(s-3)^2T=1\(s-1)(s-3)^2T=\frac{1}{s^2+1}\
(s-3)^2T = \frac{1}{s^2+1}\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{s-1} + A\delta(s-1)$$

Thanks for the correction. Here is what I've found: For the equation $(s-1)T = 1$, according to the Umberto P.'s answer, the solution is $T =  \mathrm{pv} \frac 1{s-1} + A\delta_1$. For the equation $(s^2+1)T=1$, according to the TZakrevskiy's answer, the solution is $T = \frac 1{s^2+1}$. I have two problems now...

Firstly I don't know how to combine these two cases precisely. I mean if we have $\langle (s^2+1)(s-1)T,\phi \rangle = \langle 1, \phi \rangle$ then by previous result it can be deduced that $\langle (s-1)T,\phi \rangle = \langle \frac 1{s^2+1}, \phi \rangle$ but the other result doesn't apply because the RHS is different from $\langle 1, \phi \rangle$. Secondly, I couldn't solve the case $(s-3)^2T = 1$. As you said I should look at solutions $(s-s_0)T=U$ where $U$ is a distribution but I don't know how to handle this case. All what I've found pertains to the case where RHS is $1$ or $0$.

@S.H.W. I added your example, but only the homogeneous case.

Thanks a lot for the answer. Because I'm not too familiar with distribution theory, I was looking for a more detailed derivation, like the mentioned answers. Anyway I accept your answer and maybe ask for more details in other questions.

@S.H.W. Actually I realized that it was a bit more difficult than I first thought solving the equation one factor at a time.

Yes, indeed. I’ll do more research when I have time and ask separate questions. Thanks.
